# AWS RDS MySQL audit log file daily rotation and backup

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using an *AWS RDS MySQL instance*. I have activated '**MariaDB audit plugin**' to log username+IP+query to a log.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.MySQL.Options.AuditPlugin.html

I need to rotate my log file daily and I need to store daily log file in an S3 bucket. How can I achieve this?

### What I have tried so far

1. Explored MariaDB audit plugin option settings. It has `SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATE_SIZE` and `SERVER_AUDIT_FILE_ROTATIONS` option settings. But they are not enough to achieve what I need.
2. Explored CloudWatch Logs. It seems it can rotate the logs as required but it cannot support RDS text log files.
3. Asked ChatGPT for a solution using the same information here. The solution involved using CloudWatch and Lambda function.

**NOTE**: Setting up a cron job on my laptop and and download the text log daily (using AWS CLI) and manually processing and uploading back to S3 will work. But I am looking for a simple/AWS-native solution.